# How to read all lines from file and print only last word from each line?

Tags: python

I need a python code with split or re.findall to read lines from file start with #EXTINF: then remove complete line and keep only last word or sentence ...
For example these line:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-id="" tvg-name="|AR| beIN MOVIES 1 HD" tvg-logo="" group-title="OSN & BEIN-entre",|AR| beIN MOVIES 1 HD
#EXTINF:0,GLORY 77 BOX
#EXTINF:0 group-title="Tunisia"tvg-logo="http://logo.ddnb.tn/logochanel/1.png",National 1
#EXTINF:-1,Mera Farz | Superhit Hindi Action Movie | Amrishpuri ,Sri Devi  , Nagarjuna
#EXTINF:1, FOOTBALL
#EXTINF:0,Aaryaa News
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
with open("sample.txt") as f:
    print("\n".join(l.rsplit(",")[-1].strip() for l in f.readlines()))
```

Output:

```
|AR| beIN MOVIES 1 HD
GLORY 77 BOX
National 1
Nagarjuna
FOOTBALL
Aaryaa News
```

Comment: why not `for l in f: print l.rsplit(",")[-1].strip()` ?

Comment: Thank you ... Excellent .. Works well with me